# Illegal pattern in awk

Tags: awk

In awk, we can express patterns in various ways, e. g. as regular expressions enclosed in delimiters `/.../` or as a boolean expression where a non-null value (string) or a nonzero value (number) is true. I however have this pattern and I'm wondering what it does:

```
/test/p
```

It prints all lines, whatever value `p` would have and whatever regexp is provided. How is this pattern to be read? In the documentation I didn't find anything about this. I'd expect an error message like when the ending delimiter is missing. (I know it's a common expression for sed.)

Comment: It looks like `sed` pattern to me on first look, may be your complete code could be `sed -n 'test/p' Input_file` etc?

Comment: Yes, it's sed (I added that comment to my question). That's how I accidently came to that expression. But I don't know if it's a valid awk expression (awk doesn't complain) and if so, what the meaning would be.

Comment: ...seriously? So you're asking why random code taken from a script in a different language is valid in awk? How is this a *practical* question (the criteria right next to "answerable" in https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy But now I'm curious why `awk '/test/p' infile` *does* print everything...

Comment: @CharlesDuffy If I take some random code in say Java, I can definitely tell you if it compiles and what it will do. Here, awk accepts the code (unlike it does with `/test`)...

Comment: I'm not claiming it isn't answerable. I'm claiming it isn't practical -- which is to say, that the answer has no impact on how anyone should go about the practice of writing software.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I see it as something like the "language lawyer" C++ questions, which are arguably not very useful, just interesting.

Comment: @BenjaminW., ...my concern is that you could run a fuzzer across any compiler (well, most languages' compilers) and get an indefinite stream of weird-looking things that are actually valid code. It would do the site no value to have a question for each such example.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I agree – but as long as the volume is low and questions pop up when somebody happens to bump into something, I have no problem with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `/test/` evaluates to `0` or `1`, depending on whether the current record (line) matches the regular expression.

It is string-concatenated with the result of evaluating the variable `p` (probably an empty string).

So you end up with a condition of either `"0"` or `"1"`, both of which are *true*, which means that the default action `{ print }` is executed.

The fact that the `p` looks like a regex modifier is just a coincidence; the same behaviour can be observed with any of the following, which all produce a non-empty string (`p` is assumed to be empty):

```
/test/ p  # concatenate 0 or 1 with empty variable
/test/ "" # concatenate 0 or 1 with empty string literal
0 p       # "0"
0 ""      # "0"
```

Comment: Ooooh, like `awk '0'` doesn't print anything, but `awk '"0"'` does. (Sorry, edits got crossed with your comment.)

Comment: @BenjaminW., I believe since `'0'` is like condition setting FALSE no action and `'"0"'` is like string who has some value and makes its condition TRUE so it prints IMHO.

Comment: Better example would be `awk '0""' file`.

Comment: @JamesBrown Same effect, though, as it's concatenating `0` with a string (albeit empty) and thus converting it into a string, resulting in `"0"`, right?

Comment: You are right, as you can see with `awk "/notexisting/+0"` prints nothing, `awk "/test/-1"` -> prints all non-matching lines!

Comment: Look at my last comment, it's a good proof, isn't it? `/.../0` -> prints all, `/.../+0` prints all matching lines (same with `-`), `/.../-1` prints all non-matching lines.

Comment: @steffen What you say is true but once you add `+` or `-` you are explicitly adding or subtracting, rather than concatenating strings, so it's not quite the same thing.

Comment: OK. My idea was just that the expression results in some text. If we apply a `+` or `-` operator, the text will be converted to a number. And here we can see that it actually does convert to `0` or `1`. But anyways, your answer is correct.

Comment: @steffen the point is that with the inclusion of `+` or `-` the result is no longer a string, but a number, so the behaviour changes based on whether the result is `0` (don't print) or any other number (print).